# HTML/CSS: ul li help needed

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-selectors

I am working on a CSS drop-down for a menu and having some basic HTML complications.

So lets say I have this list:

```
-Male
    -John
        -18yrs
        -5'10"
    -Tim
    -Steve
        -21yrs
        -6'1"
-Female
    -Molly
        -20yrs
        -5'3"
    -Kimberly
    -Mary
```

And...

```
div#dropMenu ul.level1
```

succesfully gives me first level: Male, Female

```
div#dropMenu li:first-child ul.level2
```

successfully gives me John, Tim, Steve

```
div#dropMenu li:last-child ul.level2
```

successfully gives me Molly, Kimberly, Mary

I need to pin point to 18yrs (under John) and pin point to 5'3" (under molly) using last-childs and first -childs.

Comment: I don't really understand. Could you try explaining it a bit better?

Comment: li:first-child ul.level3  ? (if u have any...)

Comment: @gizmodo: how about you actually insert your HTML instead of that funky looking nested list? You're confusing people, which usually means you're not going to get a very useful answer, if any.

Comment: can you create an example in http://jsfiddle.net for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't understand fully ,

try

`div#dropMenu li:first-child ul.level3 li:first-child` for 18 yrs

and

`div#dropMenu li:last-child ul.level3 li:last-child` for 5'3"